# Having Trouble With Max-Width Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I'm having trouble with the main menu in the header of my Wordpress site here: http://eptestdev.us/qa

The only way I can get it to fill the entire box is by declaring it to have a width of 950px. However, I want it to disappear when the user is on a mobile device leaving just the mobile menu.

My CSS looks like this, but it is not working:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){#access {display:none;}}
```

Not sure how I can get it to collapse otherwise. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the !important tag to your css, so that it overrides everything else. Like this:

```
display: none !important;
```

I tested this on your site and it worked.

Comment: Bingo! Thought I tried that before and it didn't work. Must have been for another class. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general it's good to avoid using `!important` - and instead use CSS's natural way of determining which rule is used.

Earlier rules (at the top of the stylesheet) are overruled by later ones:

```
.box { width: 200px; border: 1px solid black }
.box { width: 500px; }
```

The second rule will override the previous `width` declaration, giving you a 500px box with a black border.

In your case, the reason your media query rule isn't working is because it occurs before the 'normal' one. If you switch:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){#access, #copyright, .menu-footer-menu-container {display: none;}}

/* ... other rules ... */

#access, #access-footer {
  background:#000000;
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0 auto 2px;
  width:100%;
  max-height:20px;
}
```

with

```
/* ... other rules ... */

#access, #access-footer {
  background:#000000;
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0 auto 2px;
  width:100%;
  max-height:20px;
}    

@media screen and (max-width: 900px){#access, #copyright, .menu-footer-menu-container {display: none;}}
```

This rule will work without needing to use !important.

There are other ways to make rules keep: for instance, a more specific rule will be used before one that is more generic:

#menu .submenu-item { color: green; }
   .submenu-item { color: red; }

As long as your `.submenu-item divs are within a '#menu' div, they'll be green, because the subsequent`color: red` declaration doesn't have the same level of specificity.

You can read more on this here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity